# dynamic table name in Entity

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq, dbcontext

I want to call method with Table name like `db.users.select(x=> x.FirstName)` , but i made a mistake somewhere , i write like this but this returns detail about table on one row , not return table data which i want, help please

```
    public void LoadToGrid(string dbTableName)
    {
      dataGridView1.DataSource = db.GetType().GetMember(dbTableName).ToList();    
    }
```

Comment: what does `db.users.ToList()` give you ?

Comment: its works its give me datas on users table. but i want to use this method with another tables, db.schools db.citys, can i just sent to table name to method thats what i ask

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question isn't very clear, but if you mean that **You wanna do it in a generic way**, then yes that is possible. You can take advantage of the `Set<T>` method. For example:

```
public void LoadToGrid<T>(GridType grid) where T: class, new() {
    grid.DataSource = dbContext.Set<T>().ToList();
}
```

And to customize the data fields in your grid, your can add this overload

```
public void LoadToGrid<T>(GridType grid, Expression<Func<T,Object>> selectExpression) where T: class, new() {
    grid.DataSource = dbContext.Set<T>().Select(selectExpression).ToList();
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much i look for that "WHERE T: class" using it works :)