# Remote Validation in multiple classes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

This code is used to validate a unique field:

**Model:**

```
public class SubCategory
    {
        [Key]
        public int ID { get; set; }

        [StringLength(450)]

        [Remote("IsProductNameExist", "Products", AdditionalFields = "ID",
                ErrorMessage = "Product name already exists")]
        public virtual string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual string ParentName { get; set; }
    }
```

**Controller:**

```
public JsonResult IsProductNameExist(string Name, int? ID)
    {
        var validateName = db.SubCategories.FirstOrDefault
                            (x => x.Name == Name && x.ID != ID);
        if (validateName != null)
        {
            return Json(false, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        else
        {
            return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
```

All this working fine. Problem is I've multiple other classes (i.e., Category, FurtherCategories) where `Name` fields are required to be unique and I somehow want to reuse this code for all those fields as well. I can't figure out how I can pass calling class name to `IsProductNameExist` method for it to know which table it should check in the database against the calling-class ... or is there any other way I can achieve it.

Comment: `db` means your context right? and `db.SubCategories` is your DbSet right?

Comment: You could pass another paramter and do someothing like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46575714/dynamic-table-name-in-entity or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31033055/dynamic-table-names-in-entity-framework-linq

Comment: I added my answer below try it and let me know :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try using like below:

```
public JsonResult IsProductNameExist(DbSet<T> dbSet,string Name, int? ID) where T : class, new()
    {
        var validateName = dbSet.FirstOrDefault
                            (x => x.Name == Name && x.ID != ID);
        if (validateName != null)
        {
            return Json(false, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        else
        {
            return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
```

---

You can the above method like

```
public void check(string Name, int? ID)
{
    var tableNameCheck1= IsProductNameExist(_dbContext.SubCategories, Name, ID);
    var tableNameCheck2= IsProductNameExist(_dbContext.Categories, Name, ID);       
}
```

Where **dbSet** is your `dbcontext.TableName` you can pass.

Comment: OK. But how is `DbSet<T> dbSet` sent to `IsProductNameExist` on a `Remote` attribute?

Comment: You can send your `contextName.TableName` as a parameter to this method after implementing the above code. It will consider to apply conditions for that table and return the data.

Comment: Correct. But how on a `Remote` attribute, can `contextName.TableName` be sent as a parameter? Can you please show it using my `Model` code given above if possible?

Comment: I see your edited answer. Sorry but that's not the requirement. Requirement is, `Remote` attribute on `SubCategory` class is calling `IsProductNameExist`. Is there a way for `IsProductNameExist` to record name of the class which is calling it?

Comment: Not about this post, flag as "no longer needed" when read: you just suggested edit to https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/22178195 which hides most important information from error message - generic types. Please make sure to carefully review result of the edit rather than blindly convert error message to quote format.